# Send data to function

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I using DotNetNuke and I want to send data in this way:

```
<form method="post" enctype="text/plain action="Func">
```

I want to add code of my function to Home.aspx file but I can't find it.
Where must I add code of my function in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All pages in DotNetNuke are rendered in the "Default.aspx".  The "Home.aspx" you are seeing in the url is done through URL rewrites.  So your not going to find a Home.aspx page anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to that, in ASP.NET webforms, all webpages are already declared with the  tag.  You can't put two forms tags on the page, or it will break.